# peerjs not working on iOS

Tags: peerjs

I installed cordova-plugin-iosrtc. and also fixed issues related to swift3.
But still my PeerJS get stuck. 
After further digging it out  I found that it is stuck at line 519

```
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(connection.provider.options.config, optional);
```

Comment: Is it a browser compatibility issue? anything in the console log. off the top of my head there is a line of code that picks up you are using Safari and fails - you probably need to remove this